# Saved website withe javascript image link broken

Tags: javascript, image, hyperlink

I want to save this page for offline use, but after saving it completely in chrome, the image links are broken. What is the problem and a solution for something like this?

http://www.xlr8.at/8x8hexbin/

Comment: How did you save the website?

Comment: right click >> save as

Comment: Oh, that's not a good idea... Which Operating system do you use?

Comment: The website is using a lot of ressources that get lost when saving. Try a tool like [**WinHTTrack website copier**](https://www.httrack.com/)!

Comment: I am using window xp. The best Operating system out there probably.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome actually created a new folder for all the images, but the original website has its images in the same root folder as the webpage, thus the links are broken. So saving a webpage like that is not a good idea, but since this website has only 2 images, I am able to fix the link easily by moving those image back to the root folder, and fix the links on the html file.

Comment: I would tell the best way you can do is to use a caching program and find out the routes and then use that routes to recreate the website in your localhost. Like the other person said, WinHTTrack is one of the best. Also it's open source too. Plus, your comment about Windows XP being the best (yea, one of the best) shocked me. 

Comment: For my case, open up notepad, use replace function to swap the link code, and done! No-brainer!! Same concept with OS. Why do I need to upgrade to windows 10 when XP works great for me? I also have an old high end printer that no longer supported by any system other than xp, and many other applications that I need to use too, doesn't run smoothly in newer system. My desktop actually came with win8. First thing to do, down grade to XP. windows Notepad is the best programming tool!! I don't need anything else.

Comment: You are lucky mate... I couldn't handle Windows 10 and now switched to Mac. I am loving it.